# Scraping a specific h1 tag with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

i am using scrapy for the first time and  I have  been trying to scrape the number of administered vaccines  from the website of the italian government
https://www.governo.it/it/cscovid19/report-vaccini/
(the big number in the middle)

i think i have been able to set up scrapy correctly and when i write in the scrapy shell "view(response) " i correctly get the entire website, but no matter what I wrote with xpath I was not able to get the number.

the number is  within an h1 tag :

```
<h1 class="pl-2 mt-4 font-weight-light">7.894.659</h1>
```

but when i try to filter the result all i get are empty responses []

what is the right syntax to use to get this number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number that you look for is not available in the page source (Ctrl + U) of that webpage. However, you can try adding the numbers located in that page like you see in the image below to get the desired result.

[image]

This following is how I meant to achieve that:

```
import json
import scrapy

class GovernoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "reportvaccini"

    start_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/italia/covid19-opendata-vaccini/master/dati/vaccini-summary-latest.json"
    
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36",
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_url, callback=self.parse, headers=self.headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        num = 0
        json_content = json.loads(response.text)
        for item in json_content['data']:
            num+=int(item['dosi_somministrate'])
            
        yield {"Total": num}
```

Output:

```
{'Total': 7894659}
```

Comment: ah thanks for the solution! i thought that, since i could see the tag with inspect element, i could use scrapy to get it. why doesn't  it work  if  with view(response) i can see the entire website?

Answer (score 1):

When you load a webpage in scrapy shell it loads without javascript. When you `view(response)` it loads in a browser with javascript. Disable js in browser and  you'll see the website doesn't load.
You need Splash to load js websites in scrapy shell.